# Reorganizing a subject area in ERwin

Tags: database-design, erwin

I have a data model in ERwin (r7) that has about 1000 tables in it. I'm right now in the process of splitting it up into various different subject areas to make it a bit more manageable.

Here's the issue: I create a subject area with approx. 50 tables. The problem is, they appear all over the subject area in seemingly random places. Even if I zoom out as much as possible, I can't see the entire subject area, and I need to scroll around to reach the tables. Additionally, there's an obscenely large amount of unnecessary blank space between the tables.

Is there some sort of shortcut to condense all the tables in the subject area into one area (especially when there are tables that are also connected through relations)? Currently I'm moving every piece one or two at a time, but I'm hoping there's a quicker way to organize everything.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Erwin has an autolayout function that may help.

Another way you can regorganize things is to right click on a relationship line, select go to parent or go to child (whichever is appropriate) and then just drag the entity to where ever you want it.

You can also use the fit to model zoom function.

Hope this helps